# repeating a script looping over range of variables

Tags: excel, variables, applescript

I know next to nothing about apple scripting and would appreciate your help! Here is what I am trying to do:

> Write a script that copies and pastes an excel cell to word, where it
>   then automatically saves the file as a pdf. The script would then
>   automate the Apple mail program to send out a bunch of emails (with
>   attachments) based on the excel spreadsheet.

I have so far written a script that does all of this except that I am having trouble getting the script to repeat the process with the next cell and so on, until all of the cells and emails are done. Here is what I have so far:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
activate
set empName to string value of range "A4" of active sheet
set myVal to string value of range "P4" of active sheet
tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to "Macintosh HD:users:deve:desktop:C.dotx"
    tell application "Finder"
        open file theFile
        set the clipboard to myVal
        tell application "Microsoft Word"
            activate
            tell application "System Events"
                tell application process "Microsoft Word"
                    keystroke "v" using command down
                    keystroke "a" using command down
                    tell application "font" - this is just so I can fix a font issue (and I don't know how to do it using applescript so I made an automator program)
                        activate
                        delay 1
                    end tell
                    tell application "Microsoft Word"
                        save as active document file name "Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:CL:" & empName & " Letter.pdf" file format format PDF
                    end tell
                    tell application "Mail"
                        delay 2
                        set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"Message", content:myVal}

                        tell theMessage
                            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:empName, address:"XXXX@gmail.com"}
                        end tell
                        tell theMessage
                            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:CL:" & empName & " Letter.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
                            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:Work Book.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
                            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:Picture File.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
                            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:Lyrics.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
                            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:Comparison.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
                            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:Earlier Version.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph

                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
              end tell
          end tell
      end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

How would I be able to cycle this entire process such that the cells move down one each time so that `empName` and `myVal` takes their values from `A5` and `P5` ... then `A6` and `P6` all the way up to 42?

Comment: Congratulations on your first post. Change the title to express your specific question - repeating a script looping over range of variables. It may help. Do not use uppercase as emphasis. It makes many folks to just skip your question. Good that you've posted some working code. You could still refactor it a little, because horizontal scrollbar discourages indepth analysis. Show how you tried to achieve your goal and what was wrong then. It helps to get helpful answers. Welcome to StackOverflow Deve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make the row designation a variable and put your code in a repeat loop and then increase it by 1 after each iteration. Here is an example how to do it. (I also could resist eliminating some of your errantly nested tell blocks (don't nest tell blocks inside of other apps tell blocks if you're not having a reason to do so.

```
property firstRow : 5
property lastRow : 42

set r to firstRow
repeat until r is (lastRow + 1)

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        set empName to string value of range ("A" & r) of active sheet
        set myVal to string value of range ("P" & r) of active sheet
    end tell

    tell application "Finder"
        set theFile to "Macintosh HD:users:deve:desktop:C.dotx"
        open file theFile
        set the clipboard to myVal
    end tell

    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            tell application process "Microsoft Word"
                keystroke "v" using command down
                keystroke "a" using command down
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell

    tell application "font" -- this is just so I can fix a font issue (and I don't know how to do it using applescript so I made an automator program)
        activate
        delay 1
    end tell
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        save as active document file name "Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:CL:" & empName & " Letter.pdf" file format format PDF
    end tell

    tell application "Mail"
        delay 2
        set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"Message", content:myVal}

        tell theMessage
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:empName, address:"XXXX@gmail.com"}
        end tell
        tell theMessage
            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:CL:" & empName & " Letter.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:Work Book.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:Picture File.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:Lyrics.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:Comparison.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
            make new attachment with properties {file name:"Macintosh HD:Users:Deve:Desktop:Materials for Applescript:Earlier Version.pdf" as alias} at after the last paragraph
        end tell
    end tell

    set r to r + 1
end repeat
```

I didn't test this on my machine, but this answers your basic question. Post any followup help you need.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly now. Is there anyway to get it so it automatically figures out what the lastRow number is based on what has been filled in in the excel worksheet? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure. If, for instance, the cell in that row would be blank, then after getting the cell value, you could add: if myVal is "" then exit repeat